# Div onclick e.target.id not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the id of a div that was clicked.

```js
function select(e) {
  alert('ID : ' + e.target.id);
  // alert('Selected!');
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='5' onclick='select()'></div>
```

I've created a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgRZee) that you can play around with. When I click the div I get an error stating that `e` is `undefined`. However the normal  alert that just prints `Selected!` works fine though. So it's just that `e` that's the problem.

Comment: Just a note, adding handlers in HTML is not a good practice. You should use `.addEventListener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing anything as an argument so `e` would be `undefined` always. In order to get `event` object pass the `event` object as an argument.

```
<div id='5' onclick='select(event)'></div>
```

```js
function select(e) {
  console.log('ID : ' + e.target.id);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='5' onclick='select(event)'></div>
```

---

Or pass the `this` context as argument to refer the element.

```js
function select(ele) {
  console.log('ID : ' + ele.id);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='5' onclick='select(this)'></div>
```